# eventlistener beforeunload not working in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to open a popup while a user closes a tab in react using this code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload',handleUnload );
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleUnload);
    }
  }, []);
  

  const handleUnload = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
   console.log('hey')
   alert("HEY");
  }
```

is there any other way to do this or is there any way I can correct the code. Currently I'm trying to alert the user.

Comment: Why wrap `handleUnload` in `{}`?  Remove those, you should just be passing a function reference.  Should just be `window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleUnload)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to SO!

I think you have unintentionally destructured your function using the `{}`.

try this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", handleUnload);

  return () => window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", handleUnload);
}, [handleUnload]);
```

I've added `[handleUnload]` to the 2nd attribute of useEffect to prevent it adding and removing the event listener upon every state change.

Comment: You'll find the `handleUnload` event is firing, however, not all current browsers support your `PreventDefault` call. See here: [link]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event

Comment: why the not display the alert?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a ref:

```
const useUnload = (fn) => {
  const cb = React.useRef(fn);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const onUnload = cb.current;
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', onUnload);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', onUnload);
    };
  }, [cb]);
};
```

And then use this to call

```
useUnload((e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('hey')
  alert("HEY");
});
```

Comment: Why do I have to use it?

Comment: @Baryarte because everything that's defined inside a function component and is not part of the hooks flow (plain variables, functions etc) will be redefined on every re-render of the component. So, by the time you try to remove the listener (on umnount) it's by far a completely different copy of the function from the one you used when you added event listener (on mount) in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't an exact answer to what OP was asking, but I came across this while trying to figure out how to prompt only when the user has unsaved changes.  I finally got that logic working with the following code:

```js
<pre>
    let [hasUnsavedChanges, setHasUnsavedChanges] = React.useState(false);

    const [unsavedChangesCallback, setUnsavedChangesCallback] = React.useState(() => (e) => {
        let message = "You have unsaved changes, are you sure you want to leave?";
        e.returnValue = message;
        return message;
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        if (hasUnsavedChanges) {
            window.addEventListener('beforeunload', unsavedChangesCallback);
        } else {
            window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', unsavedChangesCallback);
        }
    }, [hasUnsavedChanges, unsavedChangesCallback]);
</pre>
```

Then all you have to do is update the value of `hasUnsavedChanges` whether or not your application currently has unsaved changes, and it will prompt accordingly.